# Why is my Applescript IF Loop and "Equals To" operator not working properly?

Tags: if-statement, applescript, logical-operators

I have an applescript Progress Bar Simulator and I have the user select a menu item from a list:

```
set gameMenuOption to choose from list simMenu with prompt "
Slot: " & item slot of gameslots & "

Mulla: $" & gameMulla & "
Assets: " & gameAssets & "
Speed: " & gameLoadSpeed & "Assets Per Second"
```

The prompt is basically the user's assets, money, etc. So when they select something from the menu, they can also take a look at their stats. So when they select something, it processes the input:

```
if gameMenuOption = "Shop" then
    set gameShopOption to choose from list simShop with prompt "Shop: "
else if gameMenuOption is equal to "Load Progress Bar" then
    --not finished yet!
else if gameMenuOption is equal to "Sell Assets" then
    set gameMulla to gameMulla + gameAssets
else
    error -128
end if
```

The if statement doesn't work! I have researched the syntax of an IF loop on applescript and operators and re-read my code over and over again but I don't see any errors! When the user selects an option, it just returns the -128 error that I purposely wrote but It isn't supposed to do that... I even tested it with `display dialog`:

```
--> User enters: Sell Assets
display dialog gameMenuOption
--> Returns: Sell Assets
```

But when I do this:

```
display dialog gameMenuOption = "Sell Assets"
--> Returns: False
```

Also, I thought I needed to convert it to a string but that didn't work:

`Expected expression but found “to”.`

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> The choose from list command can optionally let the user choose multiple items by setting the multiple selections allowed parameter to true. For this reason, the result of the command is always a list of selected strings.

So the result will never be `"Shop"`. It might be `{"Shop"}`.

Example:

```
set simMenu to {"Shop", "Sell Assets"}
set gameMenuOption to choose from list simMenu with prompt "Blah blah blah"
if gameMenuOption = {"Shop"} then
    display dialog "It worked" // the dialog appears
end if
```

Or (this is probably more usual) you could say

```
if item 1 of gameMenuOption = "Shop"
```

Comment: Won't converting it to a string also work? I tried that but it didn't... Thanks tho!